# GeoXML3 not returning any placemarks

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geoxml3

I have a KML file containing some polygons that has been output from an application (not sure which one). When i try to load in the xml, it seems to load fine but doesn't return any placemarks, just an empty array.

[Link to KML file](http://madebyreformat.co.uk/placemarks.kml)

I have simplified the JS just for testing to the following:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.503355, -0.127564),
  zoom: 12,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var geoxml = new geoXML3.parser({ 
  map : map, 
  singleInfoWindow : false,
  afterParse: useTheData 
});
geoxml.parse('placemarks.kml');

function useTheData(doc) {
  console.log(doc[0].placemarks);
  for (var i = 0; i < doc[0].placemarks.length; i++) {
    console.log( doc[0].placemarks[i].name );
  }
};
```

When i log the placemarks object i just get [] in the console. Is the file wrong?

I have added the following to my .htaccess

```
AddType application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml .kml
```

And replaced GeoXML.fetchXML with the following (as i was getting "Unable to retreive placemarks.kml")

```
geoXML3.fetchXML = function (url, callback) {
  function timeoutHandler() {
    callback();
  };
  $.ajax({
      type:       "GET",
      cache:      false,      
      url: url,
      success: function(xml) {
          callback(xml);
      }
  });
};
```

Comment: works for me, what version of [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3) are you using? The polys or the kmz branch?

Comment: [link to working version](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?http://madebyreformat.co.uk/placemarks.kml)

Comment: Thanks i think i needed to have the kmz branch

Comment: What version were you using? Either the [polys branch](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?http://madebyreformat.co.uk/placemarks.kml) or the [kmz branch](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?http://madebyreformat.co.uk/placemarks.kml) _should_ work (and do for me).  The trunk is old and only supports markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3) from the polys branch or the kmz branch.  The trunk is old and doesn't support polygons.

[working example with your KML using the polys branch](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?http://madebyreformat.co.uk/placemarks.kml)

[working example with your KML using the kmz branch](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?http://madebyreformat.co.uk/placemarks.kml)